# software-properties-gtk : Depends: libgtk2-perl but it is not going to be installed

Tags: package-management, winusb

I need to install winusb to burn iso image of windows 7. 
According to [this guideline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu) when i put these command one after another.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

I got an error message in my terminal which said to me

*software-properties-gtk : Depends: libgtk2-perl but it is not going to be installed*

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
sudo apt-get update
```

Then put this command

```
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

Aftermath it worked to me :)